# Tweepy lookup_user for large list of user_id

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get the user data using a large list (over 100k) of follower id's from twitter with Tweepy library (python 2.7). Below is my code:

```
def lookup_user_list(followers_id, api):
    full_users = []
    users_count = len(followers_id)
    try:
       for i in range((users_count / 100) + 1):
           full_users.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=followers_id[i*100:min((i+1)*100, users_count)]))
           print 'getting users batch:', i

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
          print 'Something went wrong, quitting...', e
          time.sleep(15 * 60)

    return full_users
```

The api argument of the function being the Tweepy authentication setup and config with consumer keys, consumer secret, access token and access secret.

When I run this like so:

```
results = lookup_user_list(followers_id, api)
```

After getting the 448 batch of user data, I get the error below:

```
Something went wrong, quitting... Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

is there a way to fix this error and iterate over full list of id to get the corresponding user data?

Answer (score 0):

In case you run into same problem, adding "While True:" before try: in my code solved this problem.

```
def lookup_user_list(followers_id, api):
    full_users = []
    users_count = len(followers_id)
    while True:
         try:
             for i in range((users_count / 100) + 1):
             full_users.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids=followers_id[i*100:min((i+1)*100, users_count)]))
             print 'getting users batch:', i
         except tweepy.TweepError as e:
             print 'Something went wrong, quitting...', e
             time.sleep(15 * 60)
         return full_users
```